# Logical Error - 2D array using ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, arraylist, 2d, variable-assignment

I am making a simpel tic tac toe game while learning Kotlin, following a tutorial.
When I input and combination as my turn in the game, let's say 1, 3  : The X appears in all places of that column. I have spent almost 3 hours finding the erorr but I think it's somthing to do with Arraylist making. Kinldy help me. Code is shown below.

```
var board = arrayListOf<ArrayList<String>>()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
for (i in 0..2){
    val row = arrayListOf<String>()
    for (j in 0..2){
        row.add("")
        board.add(row)
    }

}
    printBoard()

    var continueGame = true

    do{
println("Please enter a position. (e.g: 1, 3)")
        val input = readLine()?:""
        var x = 0
        var y = 0
        try {
            val positions = input.split(",")
            x = positions[0].trim().toInt()
            y = positions[1].trim().toInt()
            println("x is $x")
            println("x is $y")

            if(board[x-1][y-1] != "") {
                println("position already taken")

            }else{
                board[x-1][y-1] ="X"

                printBoard()
            }
        }catch (e: Exception){
            println("Invalid input, please try again")
        }

    }while(continueGame)


}

fun printBoard(){
    println("----------------")
    for (i in 0..2){
        for (j in 0..2){
            when (board[i][j]){
                "X" -> print("| X ")
                "O" -> print("| O ")
                else -> print("|    ")
            }
        }
        println("|")
        println("----------------")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `board.add(row)` outside your inner for loop (the `for (j`... loop). You are adding each row to the outer ArrayList three times, so when you start using the 2D list later and assume it only has three rows, all three of those rows are the same first row repeated, and you're ignoring the last six rows.

But actually, when you know that your collections will not ever change size, Arrays are a cleaner solution than Lists. You can create your 3x3 2D Array in one line like this:

```
val board = Array(3) { Array(3) { "" } }
```

Comment: But how to use this type of array for adding/extracting/assiging values?

Comment: The same way you're using the Lists. You shouldn't have to modify your other code except to remove that first for loop where you are creating the inner lists and adding them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I looked at the problem.

#### Debug `printBoard()`

I first looked at the `printBoard()` function. I put a breakpoint in, and saw that `board` already had 3 `X`s in it.

[image: debug view of 'board' object, showing 3 'X's]

So the problem is happening further up the chain.

#### Debugging the `X` assignment

There's only once place in your code where `X`'s are added to the board, so let's take a look there.

```kotlin
board[x - 1][y - 1] = "X"
```

I put a breakpoint on that line, and ran the program in debug mode.

[image: breakpoint where X is added to board]

When I inspect the `board` object, I see it's an `ArrayList` with 9 elements. Each element is also an `ArrayList`, each with 3 elements.

[image: debug view of 'board' object, a list of 9 lists, each with 3 elements]

In total that's 27 squares, and a tic-tac-toe board only has 9! `board` only needs 3 `ArrayLists`.

#### Debugging `board` creation

If we take a look at where `board` is created...

```kotlin
  for (i in 0..2) {
    val row = arrayListOf<String>()
    for (j in 0..2) {
      row.add("")
      board.add(row) // hmmmm
    }
  }
```

`board.add(row)` is nested inside both for loops. That means it will be called 9 times in total.

#### The Fix

So, quick fix, move `add` to the outer loop.

```kotlin
  for (i in 0..2) {
    val row = arrayListOf<String>()
    for (j in 0..2) {
      row.add("")
    }
    board.add(row) // better!
  }
```

The program now works!

[image: 1 empty ttt board, 1 ttt board with 1 X]

#### Why were there 3 `X`'s?

I think it's interesting to understand *why* the `X` was appearing on the board three times.

If we look at the two for loops, the `row` list is being created in the **outer** loop - which means only 3 `row`s will be created. But because `board.add(row)` was in the *inner* loop, it will add the **same** `row` 3 times!

We can actually see that in the debug inspection. `ArrayList@1073` is a unique ID for a specific `row` object, and it appears 3 times. So do `ArrayList@1074` and `ArrayList@1075`

[image: debug view of 'board' object, a list of 9 lists, each with 3 elements]

`board[0]`, `board[1]`, and `board[2]` all fetch the same `row` object, so in the `printBoard()` function, it loops over the first 3 elements of `board`... which are all exactly the same object!

### Preventing the problem

The next step is to think about how to stop this problem from happening in the first place. I think that the for loops were confusing - they're easy to get wrong, and have 'magic numbers'. Fortunately Kotlin has lots of useful tools we can use to write clearer code.

Kotlin's [`Array`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/#constructors) class has a constructor that accepts an `size: Int` and an initialising lambda, that is used to fill each element of the array.

Here's a demo:

```kotlin
println(
    Array(5) { i -> "I'm element $i" }.joinToString()
  )
// output: 
// I'm element 0, I'm element 1, I'm element 2, I'm element 3, I'm element 4
```

Each element of the `Array` has a value, based on `i` (the index of the array). For the tic-tac-toe board we don't care about the index, so we can ignore it.

```kotlin
// var board = arrayListOf<ArrayList<String>>() // old

var board = Array(3) { Array(3) { "" } } // new!
```

Output:

```
----------------
|    |    |    |
----------------
|    |    |    |
----------------
|    |    |    |
----------------
Please enter a position. (e.g: 1, 3)
```

There we go, a 3x3 board - nice and clear!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, for not only debuggin it my teaching me also how to solve such problem in future. Your step by step explaination has had a great impact on my understanding.